# Multiple python under different directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, path

I have two python `lib` in my Ubuntu. One library is under `usr/lib/python2.7` and another is under `usr/local/lib/python2.7`. When I use `pip` to install and update packages, they will be installed under `usr/local/lib/python2.7`. But when I run code using `python` command, it will call the library under `usr/lib/python2.7`. How could I switch from `usr/lib/python2.7` to `usr/local/lib/python2.7` ?

Note: the `python2.7` executable file only exist under `usr/bin`. For `usr/local/bin`, there is no python executable file. I am really confused about this since my laptop has the same configuration but it does not have the same issue

Comment: Umm... You just said packages are installed to, and Python runs from, `/usr/local/lib/python2.7`. So it's already consistent, right? Is there some reason you must run from `/usr/lib/python2.7`? If you just want to use `/usr/bin/python`, you can run it explicitly, or make sure your `PATH` is arranged such that `/usr/bin` is checked first (or some other directory with a symlink to `/usr/bin/python` is ahead of `/usr/local/bin` in the `PATH`). Either way, this isn't really a programming question at all; seems like [superuser](https://superuser.com/) would be the correct forum.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Hi, there is a type (forgive me). When I run 'python' command, it start python under '/usr/bin/python'

Comment: @dashenswen What is `echo $PATH` looks like, `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`, which comes first?

Comment: @pkuphy ` /usr/local/bin` come first. I was confused because I have other laptop and it shows the same configuration but do not have the same issue

Comment: @ShadowRanger Just update my description. Hope it helps

Comment: @pkuphy Just edit it. Thanks for your question. I can add more relevant information